# SharePoint online back up?

Tags: sharepoint-online, backup

I would like to know if there is back up plan in SP online. What steps would I need to take to do it.

Answer (score 4):

One of the main features of SharePoint online vs on-prem is decreasing the overhead of operations tasks like backup-restore plans and patching ...etc.

Meanwhile, if you need to take a backup, you can achieve that via the below options:

- Using 3rd party tools that can back up your Data like **AvePoint**.
- Open a service request with Microsoft to request a site collection backup.

  - Microsoft takes a backup every 12 hours and keeps it for 14 days.
- Manually backup your sites/library/list with Save site/list/library as a template.